# Makefile C with SDL2

Tags: c, makefile, sdl, ubuntu-15.04

I was given program written in C using SDL2 and nasm. I have problem with makefile: "*** Nor rule to make target'../home/amellana/Desktop/project/main.c', needed by 'main.o'"
Does anybody know what to change in my makefile?

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra

ASM=nasm
AFLAGS=-f elf64

all: myfunc mytest

main.o: ../home/amellana/Desktop/project/main.c  
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ../home/amellana/Desktop/project/main.c
mytest.o: ../home/amellana/Desktop/project/mytest.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ../home/amellana/Desktop/project/mytest.c
program.o: program.nasm
    $(ASM) $(AFLAGS) program.nasm
myfunc: main.o myfunc.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.o program.o -lSDL2 -o myfunc
mytest: mytest.o program.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) mytest.o program.o -o mytest
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f myfunc
    rm -f mytest
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general syntax for `Makefile` rules is:

```
<target>: <dependencies>
    <recipe>
```

In your case, this part:

```
main.o: ../home/amellana/Desktop/ARKO/main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c ../home/amellana/Desktop/project/main.c
```

means that in order to create target `main.o`, dependency `../home/amellana/Desktop/ARKO/main.c` must be built first. The file doesn't exist, and there is no rule defined for such a target. So, the dependency fails.

You probably have misspelled the filename, or the path is not correct.